# Smallest value for the number of edges in a non-planar graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ an undirected simple graph. $G$ is non-planar.

What's the lowest value can $|E|$ take?

I've thought about this inequality:

"If a graph $G=(V,E)$ is planar, let $|V|=v$, $|E|=e$, $r$ the number of regions. Then, the inequailities $3r\leq 2e$ and $e\leq 3v-6$ holds."

From this result, we can conclude that $|E|>3v-6$.

How can I guarantee this value is minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the inequality.

> **If** a graph is planar, **then** $e \le 3v -6$.

If a graph is not planar, we can have either $e \le 3v-6$ or $e > 3v-6$; this result says nothing about it.

What you can conclude is that *all* graphs with $e > 3v-6$ are non-planar. When $e \le 3v-6$, only some graphs are non-planar, and some are planar.

We know that a graph is planar if it does not contain a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. The smallest subdivisions of these graphs are $K_5$ itself (with $10$ edges) or $K_{3,3}$ itself (with $9$ edges). For *any* number of vertices $v\ge 6$, we can have a non-planar graph with $9$ edges: take $K_{3,3}$, and add $v-6$ isolated vertices.