# undirected simple connected stick free graph having degree sum equal to $12$ is planar.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a undirected simple connected stick free graph having degree sum equal to $12$ is planar.

I don’t know what is stick free graph.

Can someone give some comments about it?

Comment: How many edges does your graph have? That might be a start.

Comment: Apparently a stick-free graph is a graph with no vertices of degree $1$.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of the term "stick free".  In any case, it doesn't affect the result...

The condition "degree sum equal to 12" is the same as saying "has 6 edges" (since each edge has 2 endpoints), and **all 6-edge graphs are planar**.  (A graph needs at least [9 edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4140395/91818) to be non-planar; achieved by $K_{3,3}$.)